# Redirection after clicking submit button [HTML]

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I am building a webapp using ASP.NET MVC.
In my application I need to change the functionality of a submit button in HTML code. Right now after clicking submit, the data is submitted and the page redirect to some particular one (I don't know why this one) but I want to stay at the same page. How can I achieve this? I have done research but all the answers didn't work for me.

The code of the button is following:

```
<button type="submit" value="Dodaj" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#infoModal">Dodaj</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
   ...
   <input name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyController", "MyAction")) {
   ...
   <input name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

You can set manually the redirection

The first one submits to the same action and same view is rendered

or

Inside the controller, there may be a code to redirect to some other action

Comment: Using such a code I get an error:
The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Comment: @hegendroffer I havent used Anitiforgery token, then you might have to redirect from the controller itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to this:

```
document.getElementById('yourform').onsubmit = function() {
    return false;
};
```

or you can cancel page submit adding the class "cancel" in your `<input>`, example:

```
<input type="submit" ... class="cancel" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way was to change the return value in the controller after the data was saved.
Thank you !